# Get adb log and grep it to a string in IF statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to grep a string to adb logcat and if it matches it should go inside if statement else exit.THe following code doesnot work

```
if[ ./adb logcat | grep --line-buffered 'Monkey aborted due to error.' ]; then
adb logcat -d > MONKEY_WORKING_DIR/logcat_MonkeyWithoutPackageName.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use `[` if you want to test the value of an expression, not if you want to test whether a command is successful. If you're testing a command line, you just put that command after `if`.

```
if ./adb logcat | grep --line-buffered 'Monkey aborted due to error.'
then
    ...
fi
```

Also, you need to have a space between `if` and `[`.

Comment: appreciate your help.